# Exception has occured, unknown signal error when using class object again inside each function

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm trying to write a C++ code for a course I'm enrolled in, where I keep the information of the students enrolled in the course.

- I should be able to add a student to the classrrom in the user interface written in  `main` , by calling the function `void addNewStudent(int ID, string name, string surname)`, where I create my object instances, `Student`, and `Course` inside the function.
- I should also be able to search by given ID by calling the function `void showStudent(int ID)` in the main, where the function uses the `getStudent(ID)` method of the object of the class`Course`
- I did not write all the methods, but when I try to debug this code, I got the error  `" Exception has occured, unknown signal error."`

My questions are:

- What is the reason of this error? How can I fix it?
- Suppose that the user interface in the  `main`  is necessary to use as well as the functions it calls. Do I have to create a class object again inside each function as I wrote?
- Can a more effective implementation be made in accordance with the object oriented principles I have defined above?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX  10

class Student {
private:
   int ID;
   string name;
   string surname;

public:
   Student()
   {
      ID = 0;
      string name = "" ;
      string surname = "";

   }
   void setID(int ID_set);
   int getID();
   void setName(string name_set);
   string getName();
   void setSurName(string surname_set);
   string getSurName();
};

class Course {
   private:
      Student students[MAX];
      int num =0 ; // The current number of students in the course, initially 0.
      float weightQ;
      float weightHW;
      float weightF;

   public:
      Course()
      {
         students[num] = {};
         weightQ = 0.3;
         weightHW = 0.3;
         weightF = 0.4;

      }
      int getNum(); // Returns how many students are in the course
      void addNewStudent(Student new_student);
      void updateWeights(float weightQ_update, float weightHW_update, float weightF_update);
      void getStudent(int ID_given);
};

// Method declerations for the class Student

void Student :: setID(int ID_set){
   ID = ID_set;
}
int Student :: getID(){
   return ID;
}
void Student :: setName(string name_set){
   name = name_set;
}
string Student :: getName(){
   return name;
}
void Student :: setSurName(string surname_set){
   surname = surname_set;
}
string Student :: getSurName(){
   return surname;
}   

// Method declerations for the class Course
int Course :: getNum(){
   return num;
}
void Course :: addNewStudent(Student new_student){
   students[num] = new_student ;
   num = num + 1;
}
void Course :: updateWeights(float weightQ_update, float weightHW_update, float weightF_update){
            weightQ = weightQ_update;
            weightHW = weightHW_update;
            weightF = weightF_update; 
}
void Course :: getStudent(int ID_given){
   for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++){
      if(ID_given == students[i].getID()){
         cout << "Student Name & Surname : " << students[i].getName() << " " << students[i].getSurName()<<"\n";
        
      }
   } 
}

 void addNewStudent(int ID, string name, string surname){
    Student student;
    Course ECE101;
    student.setID(ID);
    student.setName(name);
    student.setSurName(surname);
    ECE101.addNewStudent(student);
   }
 void showStudent(int ID){
    Course ECE101;
    ECE101.getStudent(ID);
 }

int main(){
   Course ECE101;
   cout << "Welcome to the ECE101 Classroom Interface"<<"\n";
   cout << "Choose your option\n";
   string option_1 = "1) Add a student ";
   string option_2 = "2) Search a student by ID";
   cout << "Enter your option: ";
   int x;
   int ID;
   string name, surname;
   cin >> x;
   if (x == 1)
      cout << "Enter the student ID ";
      cin >> ID;
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Enter the student name ";
      cin >> name;
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Enter the student surname " ;
      cin >> surname;
      addNewStudent(ID, name, surname);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.

Comment: C++ is not Python. Indentation doesn't matter. It's just there to help the poor, stupid humans.

Comment: `addNewStudent` is called with a local variable `Course`. The variable `ECE101` in `main` is unused, and has no students added. So your code adds a student to a temporary course, then both the student and the course is destroyed inside of the `addNewStudent` function. Also you are doing `cin >> name` twice. I suspect the last one should be `surname`.. Run your code through a debugger.

Comment: @Brandon I edited thank you. I got the points you said but is I could not see how to define global objects and pass them to the functions at first glance.

Comment: @Brandon ```students = {}``` gives an error since students are ```Student``` object and they are arrays. Actually, two add function is created. One of them is inside in the class, but the other for user interface. I am not sure whether it is efficient or not, but it is necessary to write these two functions for the task I am trying to solve.

Comment: Change to: `Student students[MAX] = {};` in the class, OR just do nothing there (remove that line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the menu more interactive you could add a `do while` *statement* that would accept 3 options:

- register
- show data
- exit

```
int main(){
   Course ECE101;
   int x;
   int ID;
   string name, surname;

   string option_1 = "1) Add a student\n";
   string option_2 = "2) Search a student by ID\n";

   cout << "Welcome to the ECE101 Classroom Interface\n";
   cout << "Choose your option\n";
   cout << option_1 << option_2;

   cin >> x;

    do {
        if (x == 1) {
            cout << "Enter the student ID ";
            cin >> ID;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter the student name ";
            cin >> name;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter the student surname " ;
            cin >> surname;
            addNewStudent(ID, name, surname, ECE101);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Enter the student ID\n";
            cin >> ID;
            showStudent(ID, ECE101);
        }
        cout << "Choose your option\n";
        cin >> x;
    } while(x != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

`addnewStudent()` and `showStudent()` methods now accepts an instance of `Course` as an argument to be able to add *students*.

```
void addNewStudent(int ID, string name, string surname, Course &course) {
    Student student;
    student.setID(ID);
    student.setName(name);
    student.setSurName(surname);
    course.addNewStudent(student);
}

void showStudent(int ID, Course &course) {
    course.getStudent(ID, course);
}
```

the function is modified from the same **class** as well.

```
void Course::getStudent(int ID_given, Course &course) {
   for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++){
      if(ID_given == students[i].getID()){
         cout << "Student Name & Surname : " << students[i].getName() << " " << students[i].getSurName()<<"\n";
       }
   } 
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/jv8EgmME0)

Answer (score 1):

Your addNewStudent function creates a new course everytime it is called. You could pass a reference to the course as a parameter into the function and call Course.addNewStudent(student). You'll want to make sure you specify it's a reference though when you define your function or you'll just create a copy of the course.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).